# Good practice to build a rich model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, model, restangular

I've just read [this](http://blog.shinetech.com/2014/02/04/rich-object-models-and-angular-js/), explaining a way to build a rich model with Angular/Restangular.

The article shows the following code, a service retrieving, through Restangular, all the `proposals`.

```
angular.module('services', ['restangular']).
  factory('ProposalsSvc', function(Restangular) {
    Restangular.extendModel('proposals', function(obj) {
      return angular.extend(obj, {
        profit: function() {
          return this.revenue().minus(this.cost());
        },
        revenue: function() {
          return this.price().
            convertTo(this.internalCurrency);
        },
        cost: function() {
          return this.recurringEngineering.cost().plus(
            this.nonRecurringEngineering.cost()
          );
        }
        ...
      });
    });

    return Restangular.all('proposals');
  });
```

My question is:

If I want to retrieve a **specific** proposal: `/proposals/123`, **should I create another factory** => `ProposalSvc` .....?
Indeed, this one above returns specifically `Restangular.all`..., not being able to return a specific proposal with `Restangular.one("123")`.
You would tell me: "logic since there a "s" at the end of "Proposals" in `ProposalsSvc`.

I thought about the way to return `Restangular.service('proposals');`. That would let the higher layer to make the call it needs.
However, it'd mean that the controller has to depend on Restangular's api, meaning implementation detail. 
Moreover, if I need some converters, like converting some dates in the result, it would be up to my controller...ugly.
I expect the `factory` to manage the retrieved remote data (some conversions etc.) before `controller` are aware of them.

**What would be a good way to manage the CRUD, while avoiding to put all the logic in the `controller`?**

Should I create an intermediate layer, another `factory`, acting as a facade, hiding implementations to controller?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create another factory. The call to `Restangular.all('proposals')` returns a Collection which has a get() method.  So you should be able to do this: `ProposalsSvc.get(123)`.

Or you can return a service which has 3 methods: getList, one, and post. You can then do `ProposalsSvc.one().get(123)`. Note than one() returns an Element whereas getList() returns a `Promise<array>`, so the API for Service isn't consistent.  I've used a Service for simple models but for more flexibility use a Collection.

If you don't want to inject Restangular into your controller to do things like conversions, then probably a service facade would be a good idea.